# class not found Exception in Spring using ebay services

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am quiet new with spring framwork and need some help, I am using ebay services in my application to get items from ebay. when i run the application in tomcat the application crashes with the following exception.

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljavax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature;
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:920)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljavax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature;
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    com.ebay.common.ClientFactory.getServiceEndpointName(ClientFactory.java:106)
    com.ebay.common.ClientFactory.getServiceClient(ClientFactory.java:85)
    com.ebay.services.client.FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(FindingServiceClientFactory.java:34)
    com.soft.echelon.eBayService.EBayFindItem.getEBayItemsByKeywords(EBayFindItem.java:89)
    com.soft.echelon.Controllers.SearchController.onSubmit(SearchController.java:248)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

What should i do to get rid of this exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the JAX-WS Commons jar on your classpath. You can get it from here

http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/jax-ws-commons/spring/jaxws-spring/1.8/

Comment: Thanks Ravi for prompt response.
The application is doing fine on another machine